# Show that $lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{\vert z-a \vert = \epsilon} \frac{f(z)-f(a)}{z-a} = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am learning about complex analysis. In class it was written that for an $f$ holomorph in an open set containing the circle $\{z : \lvert z-z_0 \rvert \le r\}$ holds
$$lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{\vert z-a \vert = \epsilon} \frac{f(z)-f(a)}{z-a} = 0.$$

I do not see why this holds. Could you explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With $z-a=\epsilon e^{i\theta}$, $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$, the integral becomes $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{2\pi}(f(a+\epsilon e^{i\theta})-f(a))id\theta$, now it is bounded by $2\pi\sup_{\theta\in[0,2\pi]}|f(a+\epsilon e^{i\theta})-f(a)|$ and continuity of $f$ gives $\sup_{\theta\in[0,2\pi]}|f(a+\epsilon e^{i\theta})-f(a)|\rightarrow 0$ as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$.